# Mongo Aggregation, group by same field in 2 different arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to calculate the total commission earned per month per agent with the following dataset:

```
db.comm.find()

/* 0 */
{ 
month: 1,
deals: [
        { agent: { _id: 1, name: 'Joe' }, deal: { _id: 1, comm: 10000 } },
        { agent: { _id: 1, name: 'Joe' }, deal: { _id: 2, comm: 13000 } },
        { agent: { _id: 2, name: 'Sue' }, deal: { _id: 3, comm: 20000 } }
],
    referrals: [
        { agent: { _id: 1, name: 'Joe' }, referral_comm: 3000 },
        { agent: { _id: 3, name: 'Pete' }, referral_comm: 2500, other_comm: 1000 }
    ]
}

/* 1 */
{ 
month: 2,
deals: [
        { agent: { _id: 1, name: 'Joe' }, deal: { _id: 4, comm: 11000 } },
        { agent: { _id: 3, name: 'Pete' }, deal: { _id: 5, comm: 21000 } }
],
    referrals: [
        { agent: { _id: 2, name: 'Sue' }, referral_comm: 2100, other_comm: 1100 },
        { agent: { _id: 4, name: 'Judy' }, referral_comm: 1100 }
    ]
}
```

I'm getting incorrect results with the following pipeline:

```
db.comm.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$deals"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            month: 1,
            agent: "$deals.agent",
            comm: "$deals.deal.comm",
            referrals: 1
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$referrals"
    },
    {
        $project: {
            month: 1,
            agent: 1,
            comm: 1,
            referral_comm: {
                $add: [
                    "$referrals.referral_comm",
                    "$referrals.other_comm"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            month: 1,
            agent: 1,
            comm: {
                $add: [ "$comm", "$referral_comm" ]
            }
        }
    },
    { 
        $group: {
            _id: {
                month: "$month",
                agent: "$agent"
            },
            total: {
                $sum: "$comm"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The results are:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 1,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "Sue"
                }
            },
            "total" : 23500 //expected 20000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 1,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }
            },
            "total" : 30000 //expected 26000
        }, //missing Pete in Month 2
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "Pete"
                }
            },
            "total" : 24200 //expected 21000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }
            },
            "total" : 14200 //expected 11000
        }
    ], //missing Sue and Judy
    "ok" : 1
}
```

My problem is that I don't seem to find the right combination in the pipeline to combine the deals and referrals so that commissions stay with the same agent. Can this be done with the aggregation framework in Mongo, or is the only way to use MapReduce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a working pipeline, albeit expensive:

```
db.comm.aggregate([
    {
        $unwind: "$deals"
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$referrals"
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                month: "$month"
            }, 
            deals: {
                $push: {
                    agent: "$deals.agent",
                    comm: { $ifNull: ["$deals.deal.comm", 0] }
                }
            },
            referrals: {
                $push: {
                    agent: "$referrals.agent",
                    comm: {
                        $add: [{ $ifNull: ["$referrals.referral_comm", 0] }, { $ifNull: ["$referrals.other_comm", 0] }]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            month: "$_id.month",
            comms: {
                $setUnion: ["$deals","$referrals"]
            }
        }
    }, {
        $unwind: "$comms"
    }, { 
        $group: {
            _id: {
                month: "$month",
                agent: "$comms.agent"
            },
            total: {
                $sum: "$comms.comm"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

The steps are to unwind both deals and referrals in order to create new arrays with the same fields. Mongo 2.6 allows $setUnion to create a union of these different arrays. Notice that I had to add a check for missing fields with $ifNull in order to get the correct results. Finally, the $unwind and $group simply gets the combined totals across months and agents.

This then yields:

```
/* 0 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "Sue"
                }
            },
            "total" : 3200
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 4,
                    "name" : "Judy"
                }
            },
            "total" : 1100
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }
            },
            "total" : 11000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 1,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "Sue"
                }
            },
            "total" : 20000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 2,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "Pete"
                }
            },
            "total" : 21000
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 1,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 3,
                    "name" : "Pete"
                }
            },
            "total" : 3500
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : {
                "month" : 1,
                "agent" : {
                    "_id" : 1,
                    "name" : "Joe"
                }
            },
            "total" : 26000
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing with it a bit, it seems like there is a way to get this to work out with an aggregation pipeline, but frankly you've got a terrible document structure for writing a pipeline to calculate commission / (month * agent). Have you considered having each document represent a "commission event" like a deal or referral rather than having each document represent a month?

```
{
    "agent" : { "_id" : 1, "name" : "Joe" },
    "month" : 1,
    "type" : "deal",
    "deal_id" : 1,
    "comm" : 10000
}
```

The pipeline for these documents is very simple

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$group" : { 
        "_id" : { "agent_id" : "$agent._id", "month" : "$month" },
        "comm" : { "$sum" : "$comm" }
    } }
])
```

I think this alternative document structure makes sense because

- the aggregation is much easier to write (faster too, though never fast because it's processing every doc)
- you can query for the info I think you're likely to care about, and more specific info, with this structure, easier than the month document structure; for example, with your month documents, how would you query for all commissions larger than some amount?
- month documents will grow and may need to be moved on disk, which is a performance hit (applies only to mmap storage engine)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the structure is great for the way data is captured on a monthly basis, going through a couple of workflow steps of approvals and review etc. The reporting is done monthly by a small number of users when the load is low, so the structure is optimised for when the bulk of users has to get the billing submitted in a short space of time.

Comment: The above example is simplified to exemplify my problem.